# Getting stack corruption calling mysql_close, is this a bug in MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, stack-corruption

I call this code from within the Boost Test Framework which checks for stack corruption.

I get this error message:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp' was corrupted. It doesn't matter if I've successfully opened a connection or not to the mysql database.  If I comment out the mysql_close call, I get no such message.

I installed MySQL Server 5.6 and I'm linking to these directories:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\lib\opt
```

And I'm running with the DLL I've found here:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib\libmysql.dll
```

I'm wondering if the calling convention is wrong as this is a c++ project? What would be the proper way to fix this? Everything else seems to be working correctly and I get no stack corruption from any of the other mysql_ calls.

I have a function defined as:

```
void create_db(const std::string &host, const std::string &username, const std::string &password, const std::string &name)
{
    MYSQL temp;
    mysql_init(&temp);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(&temp, host.c_str(), username.c_str(), password.c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
    {
        throw mysql_db::error(mysql_error(&temp), DETAILS, mysql_errno(&temp));
    }
    std::string query_str("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+name);
    if (0 != mysql_real_query(&temp, query_str.c_str(), (unsigned long)query_str.length())) {
        mysql_close(&temp);
        throw database::error(mysql_error(&temp), DETAILS, mysql_errno(&temp));
    }
    mysql_close(&temp);
}
```

I can comment out everything to reproduce this problem leaving just:

```
void create_db(const std::string &host, const std::string &username, const std::string &password, const std::string &name)
    {
        MYSQL temp;
        mysql_init(&temp);
        mysql_close(&temp);
    }
```

MySQL Documentation for mysql_close reads as follows:

> 20.6.7.5 mysql_close()
>   void mysql_close(MYSQL *mysql)

Description

Closes a previously opened connection. mysql_close() also deallocates the connection handle pointed to by mysql if the handle was allocated automatically by mysql_init() or mysql_connect().

So I think it's okay for me to call mysql_close here.

Comment: Is your code being compiled in debug mode? Maybe the mysql library requires release mode, or has a debug mode version.

Comment: So there are 2 bugs and a design flaw in these routines. Allocation of memory should be separated out from mysql_init and deallocation of memory should be separated out from mysql_close. But in the very least, mysql_init needs to set MYSQL.free_me to true when someone passes in NULL and false otherwise. mysql_close then needs to actually check MYSQL.free_me to determine if it should call free on it. None of these things are happening. This forces every implementation to use the heap or suffer stack corruption.

Comment: Okay, I filed a bug on this and they assured me it's working correctly. So, I started thinking about what I did. Because I still suspect a calling convention problem. This is complicated. I'm trying to create a c++ library that includes both MySQL and SQLite. I'm using VisualStudio 2013. So I cannot link to MySQL statically because of different runtime libraries. But my SQLite files want to be built directly into the code. So it wants to be in a static library. I think I linked a MySQL dynamic dll into a static library and didn't define CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC= like I'm supposed to.

Comment: I either have to figure out how to do a dynamic dll with SQLite, or I have to build the MySQL libraries with VS 2013 so I can create a static library.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL library expects the `MYSQL` pointer to be an object allocated on the heap by `malloc()`; the `mysql_close()` function will end up trying to `free()` that pointer at the end. This doesn't work correctly for an object on the stack.

You need to either allocate this object yourself using `malloc()`, or allow `mysql_init()` to allocate it itself, e.g.

```
MYSQL *temp = mysql_init(NULL);
...
mysql_free(temp);
```

or

```
MYSQL *temp = malloc(sizeof(MYSQL));
mysql_init(temp);
...
mysql_free(temp);
```

Comment: So, that does fix it and it explains the problem perfectly... but the documentation does state it will deallocate the handle if it was automatically allocated by mysql_init or mysql_connect, which in this case it wasn't... this implies that it tracks this internally with a flag or something... I'm wondering if I could have done something like call memset on it to zero the memory to avoid this... I don't think it should attempt to free something it didn't allocate. Seems like a poor design. But I sincerely appreciate your response. I just think I should be able to use the stack too.

Comment: I've looked further into the MYSQL structure, it does indeed have a flag for tracking if it should delete:

    my_bool free_me;  /* If free in mysql_close */

I've also tried a memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(temp)); call prior to calling mysql_init(&temp); It still tries to delete my MYSQL object on the stack. This implies to me that mysql_init is not doing it's job of properly setting that flag to false when someone passes in an address to a MYSQL structure.

Comment: So, now I've even tried setting that flag to false just before I call mysql_close... mysql_close still deletes my structure on the stack... So there are two bugs. 1. mysql_init isn't setting temp.free_me to false. 2. mysql_close isn't checking temp.free_me before it deletes it. Honestly, mysql_close shouldn't be trying to delete anything ever... and mysql_init shouldn't be allocating anything ever. Those operations should be separate from init and close. So this basically forces me to use pointers and heap allocation when it's not necessary. It's certainly not working as documented.

Comment: It's possible that mysql_init does set the flag, since mysql_close doesn't even bother checking it... but it should be checked to make sure... I'm concerned that someone who wrote the mysql_ routines would choose potential stack corruption over potential memory leak.

Comment: I did some more testing... mysql_init never sets free_me to true. When I pass in NULL to have it malloc my instance of MYSQL, it comes back with everything zero'd out. It's almost like there are multiple people working on this code and they have different ideas how things should work. I find this kind of thing irritating. Do I need to write unit-tests around MySQL to verify it actually works in other places too?